# py2app error: "can't copy '%s': doesn't exist or not a regular file"

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm trying to pack my Python app with py2app. I'm running the `setup.py` I created, and I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 119, in copy_file
    "can't copy '%s': doesn't exist or not a regular file" % src
DistutilsFileError: can't copy '--dist-dir': doesn't exist or not a regular file

> c:\python26\lib\distutils\file_util.py(119)copy_file()
-> "can't copy '%s': doesn't exist or not a regular file" % src
```

Does anyone have any clue what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, for some reason or other, it's trying to interpret the command-line switch `--dist-dir` as a filename. Perhaps the actual switch is named something else and you typo'd it? Or perhaps it needs to be specified in a different order?

Comment: Well done. You can try this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236172/py2app-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-symlink